# Microsoft SQL server hosting that supports DTS

Tags: sql-server, hosting, dts

Could someone suggest a shared SQL Server solution that supports DTS packages?

**Update:**
I was hoping to use the PostgreSQL ODBC driver and a DTS package to keep data synchronized between MSSQL server and Postgres.  After getting my hands on SQL Server 2005 and attempting to do this I realized SSIS doesn't seem to play nicely with the PostgreSQL ODBC driver.

I gave up on the SSIS/DTS solution and have written a program using JDBC which runs happily on my Linux server.

Comment: You might have more luck asking about SSIS than about DTS.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any hosting services that provide DTS or SSIS as a feature. However, if what you are trying to achieve by using DTS/SSIS is a way to do your own backups/data transfers then I would suggest you look into the [Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing Services](http://www.codeplex.com/sqlhost/). [Go Daddy supports it](http://help.godaddy.com/article/3435).

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Edgewebhosting](http://www.edgewebhosting.net/) before and used DTS packages for pushing data to sites.  I have no affiliation with them, it worked well for the job.